# How can i access value with labelContent in MarkerWithLabel having space between them

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

when i access the value from my json data in google map api  and adding marker with the help of MarkerWithLabel, labelContent:building.Post-completion. but when I running this code, it says,ReferenceError: completion is not defined,but my json data have following type. I think there is a issue regarding the - character in Post-completion,which cannot read a single sentence.but there is a value associated with it.

```
  var activity_status = [{"Completion": 0, "Pipeline": 0,  "Implementation": 5, "country": "MYANMAR", "Post-completion": 138, "Cancelled": 0},
                       {"Completion": 0, "Pipeline": 0, "Implementation": 0, "country": "Bahrain", "Post-completion": 0, "Cancelled": 0},
                      {"Completion": 0, "Pipeline": 0, "Implementation": 0, "country": "ZIMBABWE", "Post-completion": 1, "Cancelled": 0},
                      {"Completion": 0, "Pipeline": 0, "Implementation": 12, "country": "MONGOLIA", "Post-completion": 34, "Cancelled": 0},{}];






 for(var j= 0; j < activity_status.length; j++) {
        (function(i) {
         var building = activity_status[i];

        geocoder.geocode({'address':building.country}, function(results,status){

          if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
            var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
              position:new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng()),
              title:building.country,

              map:map,
              labelContent:building.Post-completion, 
              labelAnchor:new google.maps.Point(6,22),
              labelClass:"labels",
              labelInBackground:false,
              icon:"circle2.png"
            });
             console.log(building.country)
          }
          else{
                 console.log("Geocode was not  succcessful for the following reason:" + status);
             }
        });
       })(j);
```

Comment: A '-' is not allowed in a javascript variable name [Valid Characters for JavaScript Variable Names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access it like you would an array. `building['Post-completion']`